# What vcredist package do I install on a 64 bit machine with a 32 bit app?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, vcredist

I am trying to get an installer working for a 32 bit app on 64 bit machines. I originally included the 64bit version of the vcredist package and scripted it so it would use these on a 64 bit machine. So is it kosher to install the 32bit ones on the 64bit machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should install the 32-bit redistributables.  The 64-bit redistributables won't help a 32-bit application, and the installer for the 64-bit redistributables won't automatically install 32-bit redistributables.